# set attributes in a has_many_though relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have three models: `Company`, `User` and `Employment`. Each Company has many users though their Employments, and a user might belong to several companies through his employments.

Now, the tricky part: let's say my User1 belongs to 2 companies. He is SUPER_ADMIN in the first compnay, but just BASIC_USER in the second one. What would be the best way to define his roles ?

I used to have a simple has_many relationship between Company and User, which allowed me to simply set a `is_admin` attr on my User, but obviously this won't do with the new HMT relationship.

I thought of defining an array of IDs for each company, that would include the IDs of each admin user, but I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner way around.

Comment: You can add a `role` field in `employment` through table

Comment: IMO you should use employement to define what's role user have in specific company. This way solve your HTM relationship also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above scenario, you can use intermediate table i.e. `Employment` table to save all details of a user and it's associate company.

As `Employment` table will have ids of both user & company it will be easy for you to keep extra information related to user and company. Just add `role` column in this and use this to get information

Comment: Yep, just had to add a method to retrieve and pluck admin users. Quite brilliant, good sir.